# Gmap.Net получить координаты для маркера

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Необходимо добавить 2000 объектов на карту. Код снизу добавляет один маркер +- в секунду. Как эффективно получить координаты зная только адрес?

```
foreach (var branch in db.Branches)
{
   GmapView.SetPositionByKeywords(branch.Address);
   var pos = GmapView.Position;
   var marker = new GMapMarker(pos)
     {
      Shape = new BranchControl()
     };
   GmapView.Markers.Add(marker);
}
```

Comment: Я вот потестил на GMap.NET.Windows.1.7.7 - так вот у меня около 100 маркеров почти моментально добавляются, может у Вас точки уж очень далеко друг от друга расположены?

Comment: хм, интересно, возможно долго с базы данных достается или столько картинок ему сложно закидывать, сейчас проверю. нет, все в пределах одного города. Других вариантов не знаете?

Comment: попробуйте закешировать данные с базы или задать руками статические данные.

Comment: вся проблема в GmapView.SetPositionByKeywords(branch.Address); достается в среднем 2 секунды, в лучшем случае 111 мс, интернет 4 мегабита, все работает стабильно(до это программа парсит ~70 сайтов за 40 секунд). Задал литерал вместо обращения к базе данных - такое же время показывает(а именно "г.Москва, ул.Покровка, д.40"), так же долго достается, хотя просто "Москва" отрабатывает за 1-2мс в том же участке кода

Comment: что на гугл картах, что на OpenStreetMap

Comment: просто смех, "г.Москва, ул.Покровка, д.40" - 2 секунды, "Москва, ул.Покровка, д.40" 2 миллисекунды(прогнал раз 10, на OSP картах). ох уж эти карты, никогда не поймешь где тебе придется веселиться всю ночь:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для нормальной работы нужно задавать аргумент у `SetPositionByKeywords()` как адрес указан в картах(на картах показывается оптимальный адрес):
`SetPositionByKeywords("Россия, Москва, Нововладыкинский проезд, 2с1")` выполняется пару мс,
`SetPositionByKeywords("Нововладыкинский пр-д, д.21, строение 1")` - пару секунд;
`SetPositionByKeywords("Россия, Москва, улица Усиевича, 29к1")` - пару мс,
`SetPositionByKeywords("Россия, Москва, Усиевича улица, 29к1")` - пару секунд.

Мои наблюдения дали следующую картину(на примере `Яндекс.Карты`) для избежание ожидания ответа в пару секунд:
1) `Страну` и `город` лучше указать, во избежание путаницы
2) `улица`,`проезд`,`переулок`, `проезд`, `бульвар`, `проспект`, `шоссе`, `деревня`, `корпус`, `поселок`, `набережная`, `площадь` указывать с "правильной" стороны и писать в явном ввиде(не `ул.`, а `улица`)
3) `г.`, `д.` убирать
4) `строение` писать в сокращенном виде без пробелов( не `д.24, строение 3`, а `24с3`)

Эти правила помогли с 17 минут(~1800 вызовов `SetPositionByKeywords()` ) уменьшить время до ~10 секунд